# pd.groupby().expanding().mean() gives NaN where it should not

Tags: pandas, nan, rolling-computation, expansion

I have a dataframe of this type

```
         gvkey   fyear      cusip    ebit  ...  ind  status  pretax_adj     pretax
12        1000  1973.0  000032102   3.277  ...    0       0   -0.118750   2.997750
13        1000  1974.0  000032102   3.494  ...    0       0   -1.312500   3.651500
14        1000  1975.0  000032102   5.335  ...    0       0    1.435417   2.788583
15        1000  1976.0  000032102   7.143  ...    0       0    0.493750   5.680250
16        1000  1977.0  000032102   3.503  ...    0       0    0.354167   2.908833
       ...     ...        ...     ...  ...  ...     ...         ...        ...
550010  203573  1994.0  522000108   0.498  ...    0       0    0.000000  -3.867000
550536  209418  1994.0  927191106   8.965  ...    0       1    0.841176   5.634824
551125  220508  1993.0  400488409  95.255  ...    0       0   46.611429  38.567571
551126  220508  1994.0  400488409  62.230  ...    0       0   25.794286  38.528714
554555  277918  1994.0  29355M200 -24.665  ...    0       1    0.000000 -25.021000
```

I want to calculate a rolling average with a minimum window of 1 observation on the column `pretax` grouping by `gvkey`. I use the following

```
df['new']=df.groupby('gvkey')['pretax'].expanding(min_periods=1).mean().reset_index()['pretax']
```

I get the following

```
         gvkey   fyear      cusip  ...  pretax_adj     pretax         new
12        1000  1973.0  000032102  ...   -0.118750   2.997750    0.694887
13        1000  1974.0  000032102  ...   -1.312500   3.651500    0.715974
14        1000  1975.0  000032102  ...    1.435417   2.788583    3.201076
15        1000  1976.0  000032102  ...    0.493750   5.680250    3.505423
16        1000  1977.0  000032102  ...    0.354167   2.908833         NaN
       ...     ...        ...  ...         ...        ...         ...
550010  203573  1994.0  522000108  ...    0.000000  -3.867000         NaN
550536  209418  1994.0  927191106  ...    0.841176   5.634824         NaN
551125  220508  1993.0  400488409  ...   46.611429  38.567571         NaN
551126  220508  1994.0  400488409  ...   25.794286  38.528714         NaN
554555  277918  1994.0  29355M200  ...    0.000000 -25.021000         NaN
```

As you can see, I obtain NaNs where they should not be. For example notice that for `gvkey==220508` I have 2 observations and thus the second value `fyear==1994`should be calculated. Why does this happen?

Comment: Why should `fyear` be calculated? You select `pretax` for the mean calculation. Your error occurs because you reset the index and append the column `new` to incorrect rows of the original dataframe.

Comment: Please include a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). With your example data it is not possible to produce a correct output because the error depends on rows that are not included in your question.

Comment: You are perfectly right about the index mismatch, I noted myself as well.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution: it was due to a mistake of mine. I had perform a filtering on the dataframe with a boolean mask previously built, and then applied the `expanding`command with the `.reset_index()` method. The results was that the index of the dataframe and of the result from `expanding`were the same in terms of dimensions, but did not match in terms of `gvkey`. Maybe this can help someone else